# Tabla dinámica - auto-show

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código donde edito el campo de una fila en una tabla, pero quiero que este sea mas didactico, es decir, al momento de editar un campo este salte al siguiente campo donde voy a editar. Tengo una function de success donde deberia saltar al siguiente campo para editar que seria el `Item`, pero nose porque no funciona.

```js
$('#TablaDespachos').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.pedido',
        title: 'pedido',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
         type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Este campo es necesario';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
          
            // $('#TablaDespachos tbody .editable').on('hidden', function(e, reason) {
            //
            //         var $next = $(this).closest('tr>td').next().find('.Clasificacion');
            //         setTimeout(function() {
            //             $next.editable('show');
            //         }, 300);
            // });
        }
    });
    var Item = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        Item.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#TablaDespachos').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        source: Item,
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Este campo es necesario';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="TablaDespachos" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr id="EncabDespachos">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Pedido</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

He visto un ejemplo en la siguiente pagina. [LINK](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) debes presionar el checkbox `auto-open next field` al momento de editar este salta al siguiente campo para editar. Me gustaria algo asi, espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno agarre tu mismo código y en el **success** lo que hice fue irme a un nivel superior osea al **tr** con el `parent()` y luego buscar con `find()` el hijo de esa fila que contenga la clase **Item**, luego de eso le doy un `toggle()` para que muestre el campo para editarlo:

```js
$('#TablaDespachos').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.pedido',
        title: 'pedido',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Este campo es necesario';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
        
          $(this).parent().find(".Item").editable('toggle');
        }
    });
    var Item = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        Item.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#TablaDespachos').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        source: Item,
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Este campo es necesario';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="TablaDespachos" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr id="EncabDespachos">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Pedido</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select" data-source='[{value: 1, text: "text1"}, {value: 2, text: "text2"}]'>Item2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select" data-source='[{value: 1, text: "text1"}, {value: 2, text: "text2"}]'>Item1</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Esta saltando al próximo select funcionando bien pero me sale esto en el select `Error when loading list` aparte me crea `<tr><td></td></tr>`

Comment: El error es por que el tipo select no tiene data, allí le agregue data para que veas que funciona, y no veo que agregue <tr><td></td></tr>.

Comment: Con esta linea de codigo funciona bien `$(this).parent().find(".Item").click();` pero gracias me ayudaste mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Como no aclarás que error, voy a suponer que primero es el que da tu código-ejemplo al ejecutarlo: ***"message": "TypeError: a.fn.popover is undefined"***

El problema es el orden en que incluís las librerías, debería ser algo así como:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

*Nota: respecto al código en sí, a simple vista aparecen varios problemas como la declaración duplicada de la tabla, la función success comentada, etc. Pero no eso si eso está incluído en tu pregunta o si son modificaciones de pruebas por el error de las librerías. En cualquier caso, también ahí hay problemas.*

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda a reparar el post. Ahora funciona el editable